# Merging two multidimensional arrays in Javascript by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays:

```
var array1 = [['email1', object1],['email2', object2],['email3', object3],['email4',object4]]
var array2 = [['email1',[['a1','b1']]],['email3',[['a3','b3']]], ['email4',[['a4','b4'],['a4a','b4a']]]
```

I need to merge them by email so the resulting array will look like, without duplicate email:

```
var mergedarray = 
[['email1', object1, [['a1', 'b1']]],['email2', object2],['email3', object3, ['a3', 'b3']],['email4',object4,[['a4','b4'],['a4a','b4a']]]]
```

My brain hurts looking at those multimultidimensions..Any advice?

Comment: Shouldn't they be strings...?

Comment: Where does the `[]` in the second position in the result come from?

Comment: This is an awful way of storing data.

Comment: What if they become unordered...what if the email numbers get broken...how will this work?

Comment: @JackBashford They are already unordedered, you can see that array2 is missing 'email2'. I need to merge them by email string value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Couldn't implement any of the advices (probably because of my low skill), I ended up turning arrays into objects to assign key-value pairs, so new data looked like:

```
var array1 = [{email:'email1', obj:object1, data:[]},{email:'email2', obj:object2, data:[]},{email:'email3', obj:object3, data:[]},{email:'email4',obj:object4, data:[]}];
var array2 = [{email:'email1',data:[{'a1','b1'}]},{email:'email3',data:[{'a3','b3'}]}, {email:'email4',data:[{'a4','b4'}]},{email:'email4',data:[{'a4a','b4a'}]}];
```

After that I used a loop to push objects data from one array into another:

```
 for (var x in array1) {
    var res = array1[x].email;

    for (var z in array2) {
      var cod = array2[z].email;
      var q = 0;
      if (res == cod) {
        array1[x].data.push(array2[z].data[0]);
        q++;
      }

    }
  }
```

And the result is:

```
var array1 = [{email:'email1',obj:object1,data:[{'a1','b1'}]},{email:'email2',obj:object2,data:[]},{email:'email3',data:[{'a3','b3'}]},{email:'email4',obj:object4,data:[{'a4','b4'},{'a4a','b4a'}]}];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   const hash = new Map();

   for(const [email, ...rest] of [...array1, ...array2]) {
     if(hash.has(email)) {
       hash.get(email).push(...rest);
     } else {
        hash.set(email, [email, ...rest]);
    }
  }

  const result = [...hash.values()];
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of array2 for faster search and use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on first array or vice-versa.

```js
var array1 = [['email1', 'object1'], ['email2', 'object2'], ['email3', 'object3'], ['email4', 'object4']]
var array2 = [['email1', [['a1', 'b1']]], ['email3', [['a3', 'b3']]], ['email4', [['a4', 'b4'], ['a4a', 'b4a']]]]

let map2 = new Map(array2);

let out = array1.map(([key, val]) => [key, val, map2.get(key) || []]);
console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map over the second array and check if the first element is in any of the arrays in the first array, and then push the second element if that returns true:

```js
var array1 = [['email1', 'object1'],['email2', 'object2'],['email3', 'object3'],['email4','object4']]
var array2 = [['email1',[['a1','b1']]],['email3',[['a3','b3']]], ['email4',[['a4','b4'],['a4a','b4a']]]]

array2.forEach((arr2, i2) => {
  array1.map((arr1, i1) => {
    if (arr1[0] == arr2[0]) {
      array1[i1].push(array2[i2][1])
    }
  })
})

console.log(array1)
```